# Taking BusID output from lspci and storing in a variable

Tags: bash, shell-scripting, lspci

I am trying to get the BusID's of each video card stored in a server and putting them in a variable each to be used for an input to a simple find and replace perl script. How would I go about getting the BusID's of each device listed when I run "lspci | grep VGA" for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to delineate output by spaces. In the fragment below, (assuming a single line was returned by the `lspci | grep VGA`) the `$1` refers to the first component up to a space. $2 would be VGA, $3 compatible, etc ... like this:

```
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware Inc Abstract SVGA II Adapter
```

In Bash, you would extract the component via awk and assign it to $var, like so:

```
var=$(lspci |grep VGA | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

`echo $var` should return `00:0f.0`

Comment: After re-reading your question, I may have answered the 'wrong' question.  Does this help you or were you trying to parse the output of lspci | grep VGA from within perl?

Comment: This works for getting that part, unfortunately I needed only the first two digits as they are the BusID. This is how I ended up doing it.

@lspciout = `lspci | grep VGA`
foreach my $line (@lspciout){
$_=$line;
($first)=/^(\w\w).+$/;
}